# How to give dynamic values for short_name in Manifest.json file in NextJs in PWA

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm new to NextJs and typescript. Need to change the short_name in Manifest.json file dynamically based on the userName for progressive web apps.

In NextJs we link the manifest.json file in _document.tsx file. I'm not able to dynamically change the short_name or do an API hit in _document.tsx file. Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamic manifest.json file in PWA and ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997333/how-to-create-dynamic-manifest-json-file-in-pwa-and-reactjs)

Comment: Tried this approach , As id is added and try to override the short_name in _app.tsx it is not working @juliomalves