# "Save to Home Screen" only saves the root path

Tags: android, ios, homescreen

I have a web app specifically designed for mobile use. The user gets a login URL containing a tenant ID in the query, e.g. `https://m.example.com/login?tenant=123`

If I try to add this to the home screen, the link saved is just the root path, `https://m.example.com/`, so the tenant ID is lost in the process. I observe the same behavior on both iPhone and Android.

Can I preserve the tenant ID when adding to home screen?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887676/can-the-url-for-the-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone-safari-be-customized) seems related, except the question describes the exact opposite behavior, indicating that the default behavior has changed since 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to vote to close my own question, as it's almost a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/385417/add-to-home-screen-saves-wrong-url). But SO requires the duplicate to be on SO.

If there is a `manifest.json` file with a `start_url` field, that will suggest which URL to add to the home screen. Our application was bootstrapped with create-react-app, which creates a skeleton manifest with `start_url: "/"`, which is why we observed that behavior. By removing that line from the manifest, it works as intended.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259201/158483) also demonstrates how the manifest can be generated dynamically on the front-end. That functionality could be relevant in this scenario, where you need to have the tenant id in the URL, but still maybe want to have a specific start page.